# RestClientConfig AbstractElasticsearchConfiguration connect to docker service on same network

Tags: spring-boot, docker, elasticsearch

I am using spring data elasticsearch to connect to elasticesearch in a docker container. The code i use can be found here under

13. High Level REST Client

https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/elasticsearch/docs/current/reference/html/#reference

```
static class Config {

  @Bean
  RestHighLevelClient client() {

    ClientConfiguration clientConfiguration = ClientConfiguration.builder() 
      .connectedTo("elasticsearch")
      .build();

    return RestClients.create(clientConfiguration).rest();                  
  }
}
```

The spring boot app and the docker elastic search is on the same network because they are both in the same directoy (Both spring boot docker-compose and elasticsearch docker-compose file).

My elasticsearch docker-compose is as such

version: '3'

```
services:
  elasticsearch:
    image: docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:6.8.6
    container_name: elasticsearch
    environment:
      - cluster.name=cluster
      - bootstrap.memory_lock=true
      - "ES_JAVA_OPTS=-Xms512m -Xmx512m"
    ulimits:
      memlock:
        soft: -1
        hard: -1
    volumes:
      - ./config/elasticsearch/elasticsearch.yml:/usr/share/elasticsearch/elasticsearch.yml
      - esdata6:/usr/share/elasticsearch/data    
    ports:
      - "9200:9200"
  kibana:
    image: docker.elastic.co/kibana/kibana:6.8.6
    container_name: kibana
    volumes:
      - ./config/kibana/kibana.yml:/usr/share/kibana/kibana.yml
    restart: on-failure
    ports:
      - "5601:5601"

volumes:
  esdata6:
```

I am getting the error

```
Caused by: java.io.IOException: elasticsearch
Caused by: java.net.UnknownHostException: elasticsearch
```

How can i let my spring boot see the elasticsearch service name and resolve it? I think it is something to do with the RestClients.

Comment: Does your application itself run in Docker container or not?

Comment: Yes it does. It is on the same network because the docker-compose of my application and the docker-compose of the elasticsearch is in the same folder. I spin up the elasticsearch first with docker-compose -f ./docker-compose-elasticsearch.yml, then i spin up the application with docker-compose -f ./docker-compose.yml.

Comment: You have to make the dockerized application itself run within the same network the ElasticSearch and Kibana does, otherwise they cannot see each other. The URL of the ElasticSearch is accessed from `localhost:9200` in the outer network but as `elasticsearch:9200` from the containers.